# When running Numba code on a CUDA GPU, I notice one of my CPU cores stays at 100%. Is this limiting performance?

Tags: python-3.x, cuda, gpu, gpgpu, numba

I have a test code that is computationally intense and I run that on the GPU using Numba. I noticed that while that is running, one of my CPU cores goes to 100% and stays there the whole time. The GPU seems to be at 100% as well. You can see both in the screenshot below.

[image]

My benchmark code is as follows:

```
from numba import *
import numpy as np
from numba import cuda
import time


def benchmark():
    input_list = np.random.randint(10, size=3200000).astype(np.intp)
    output_list = np.zeros(input_list.shape).astype(np.intp)

    d_input_array = cuda.to_device(input_list)
    d_output_array = cuda.to_device(output_list)

    run_test[32, 512](d_input_array, d_output_array)

    out = d_output_array.copy_to_host()
    print('Result: ' + str(out))


@cuda.jit("void(intp[::1], intp[::1])", fastmath=True)
def run_test(d_input_array, d_output_array):
    array_slice_len = len(d_input_array) / (cuda.blockDim.x * cuda.gridDim.x)
    thread_coverage = cuda.threadIdx.x * array_slice_len
    slice_start = thread_coverage + (cuda.blockDim.x * cuda.blockIdx.x * array_slice_len)

    for step in range(slice_start, slice_start + array_slice_len, 1):
        if step > len(d_input_array) - 1:
            return

        count = 0
        for item2 in d_input_array:
            if d_input_array[step] == item2:
                count = count + 1
        d_output_array[step] = count


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import timeit
    # make_multithread(benchmark, 64)
    print(timeit.timeit("benchmark()", setup="from __main__ import benchmark", number=1))
```

You can run the code above to repro if you got python 3.7, Numba and codatoolkit installed. I'm on Linux Mint 20.

I got 32 cores - doesn't seem right to have one 100% while everyone else seats idle.

I'm wondering why that is, if there is a way to have other cores help with whatever is being done to increase performance?

How can I investigate what is taking 100% of a single core and know what is going on?

Comment: Thank you! If you want to move that into an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CUDA kernel launches (and some other operations) are *asynchronous* from the point of view of the host thread.  And as you say, you're running the computationally intense portion of the work on the GPU.

So the host thread has nothing to do, other than launch some work and wait for it to be finished.  The waiting process here is a [spin-wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22424090/what-difference-between-cudadevicescheduleblockingsync-and-cudadevicescheduleyie) which means the CPU thread is in a tight loop, waiting for a status condition to change.

The CPU thread will hit that spin-wait here:

```
out = d_output_array.copy_to_host()
```

which is the line of code after your kernel launch, and it expects to copy (valid) results back from the GPU to the CPU.  In order for this to work, the CPU thread must wait there until the results are ready.  Numba implements this with a *blocking* sync operation, between GPU and CPU activity.  Therefore, for most of the duration of your program, the CPU thread is actually waiting at that line of code.

This waiting takes up 100% of that thread's activity, and thus one core is seen as fully utilized.

There wouldn't be any sense or reason to try to "distribute" this "work" to multiple threads/cores, so this is not a "performance" issue in the way you are suggesting.

Any CPU profiler that shows hotspots or uses PC sampling should be able to give you a picture of this.  That line of code should show up near the top of the list of lines of code most heavily visited by your CPU/core/thread.